# ADD TO CART BY CSV UPLOAD

Tags: addtocart, csv

I want to create an extension where a user can make a bulk order by uploading a csv file - this extension would be same as https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/30402/ I am new to magento extension.

Share the tutorial of how to extract the value of file and bring it in cart

Answer (score 0):

What is your magento version? I would search for an extension or create one since this is not standard included in any magento. They can send the list to you and u can quickly select everything admin side and can create orders like that for them. That would be about the same as they send u the csv fille. Not sure if u can use an xml import maybe.